# Is there a convenient way to convert multiple data types with ncap2?

Tags: netcdf, nco

I would like to know if exists a manner to conveniently convert multiple data types of a file using e.g. **ncap2**.
More in details, I would like to *convert all the variables with type `double` to type `float`.*

I understand the way to do it is `ncap2 -s 'var1=var1.convert(NC_FLOAT);var2=var2.convert(NC_FLOAT)' in.nc out.nc` but this is not convenient when having a lot of variables.
Is there a smarter way to do this?

Cheers

Comment: if you were doing this to save space, another thing you could try would be netcdf4 zip compression, e.g. cdo -f nc4 -z zip_9 copy in.nc out.nc

Comment: Thanks Adrian! I was thinking to use the `ncap2` built-in `-L n` option to select an n level of deflation. Nevertheless, I would like the data type no to be doubles yet floats.

Comment: i'm afraid the only way I know to do it in cdo is to extract the variables using selvar, convert to float and then stick back together using cat.  But that is very clunky, so I think an nco based solution is likely to be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. This is relatively easy to do with "variable pointers" aka "vpointers" described [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#vp). Try this:

```
ncap2 -s '@all=get_vars_in();*sz=@all.size();for(*idx=0;idx<sz;idx++){@var_nm=@all(idx);*@var_nm=*@var_nm.convert(NC_FLOAT);}' in.nc out.nc
```

Responding to question in comments below:

Your attempt does not work because `convert()` makes the change on the RHS. The RHS change is volatile until it is saved in a LHS variable. A small change in your script fixes this:

```
ncap2 -s '@all=get_vars_in();*sz=@all.size();*idx=0;for(idx=0;idx < sz;idx++){@var_nm=@all(idx);if(*@var_nm.type() == NC_DOUBLE) *@var_nm=*@var_nm.float();}' in.nc out.nc
```

Also note that `ncpdq` appears to be the best operator to use for your purposes, because it has a [packing map](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncpdq) that automagically converts all doubles to floats, and you can enable compression easily at the same time too:

```
ncpdq -7 -L 1 --pck_map=dbl_flt in.nc out.nc
```

Comment: Thanks!! The link was not working for me, I found the documentation at http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#Vpointer .

Comment: I just tried the script and it actually converts every variable into `floats`. However, I'd like just the variable of type `double` to be converted. I tried the following:
`ncap2 -s'@all = get_vars_in();*sz = @all.size();*idx=0;for (*idx = 0; idx < sz; idx++){@var_nm = @all(idx);if (*@var_nm.type() == NC_DOUBLE){*@var_nm=*@var_nm;*@var_nm.convert(NC_FLOAT);}}' file.in file.out`
but it doesn't seem to change anything from the original file.

Answer (score 2):

CDO permits conversion to 32 bit float too, although I should emphasize that this doesn't exactly answer the question as it converts *everything* to float, so Charlie's answer is the correct one, this is more for general info to readers of this question.

```
cdo -b f32 copy in.nc out.nc
```